# Would you tell me more about preceding adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, word-order

Would you possibly tell me which of them is more polished or fluent?

> - By carrying out due research and studies on the **received** scientific reports from/by someone
> - By carrying out due research and studies on the scientific reports **received** from/by someone

I made some mistakes, so I have edited this question.

Comment: What do you mean by *influenced*? Influenced by what? Both of these are acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

(1) is not grammatical because the receiver is separated from "received."

(2) is correct, however you should put an ellipsis after both examples to show they're incomplete sentences.

Comment: I think the trailing adjective formation is actually a relative clause: "reports [that we have] received". In casual speech you'd definitely make those words explicit. In a scientific report, on the other hand, it's common to get rid of the pronouns.

Comment: Absolutely, and I prefer the inferred relative clause to the adjectival use.

Comment: I have edited my question. Would you possibly respond to my question?

Comment: In the new form, the 1st is definitely wrong. The 2nd is correct in the same way as before, as an implicitly formed relative clause.

Comment: that's how I see it too